# Would continuously increasing curvature of space explain seeming expansion of the universe?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, space-expansion, curvature, redshift

Could expanding universe phenomenon be explained by slowly but continuously increasing curvature of space around masses like galaxies and galaxy clusters? In other words, I am curious whether the observations from continuously increasing curvature would resemble/mimic the observations of seemingly expanding universe, without any actual expansion or with significantly less actual expansion?

By mentioning continuously increasing curvature, I imagine galaxies and galaxy clusters "sinking" increasingly deeper into the spacetime. Similarly to how black holes are sometimes imagined as continuously sinking, but with a much slower rate. Has such a theory been developed somewhere sometime?

Expanding universe would cause redshift. If curvature around massive objects were increasing continuously, it might also lead to redshift. What would be the observational differences of continuously increasing curvature of space around masses as compared to the observational effects of expanding universe? Which existing observational evidence would be compatible with a hypothesis of increasing curvature and which existing evidence seems to disagree with it?

I suspect that effects from gravitational lensing might be affected by the slowly but continuously increasing curvature. Is that so? Are there any known discrepancies in observed gravitational lensing around galaxies and galaxy clusters as compared to the current predictions of expanding universe theory or general relativity?

I am a layman, have no formal education in physics, but have been interested and followed popular science news in physics and space since young age.

Comment: @Proscionexium I need to clarify. My focus of the question is - could a hypothesis of increasing curvature around masses replace the theory of expanding universe, by explaining the observations by alternative mechanism? I am not asking whether expanding universe would increase curvature of space.

Comment: @Proscionexium I am not sure I am able to align your last comments with the fact that spacetime definitely is considered to be curved around masses in general relativity. Is that correct? What I am asking here is, how would it match with our observations if that curvature around masses were slowly but continuously increasing?

Comment: @Proscionexium If universe is locally curved, then where does "local curvature" end? Isn't this curvature hierarchical across different scales of galaxy groupings?

Comment: @ProfRob Are you saying hypothesis of dark energy is irrelevant to the theory of expansion of universe? To be clear, I am not saying dark energy is the ONLY hypothesis explaining expansion. But there needs to be an explanation as good as dark energy. I do not care about the truth of dark energy specifically, just about explaining the same observations it tries to explain.

Answer (score 4):

The immediate problem I see with this idea is that a "continuously increasing curvature" of spacetime around galaxies would be observable as an increased redshift of light coming from older galaxies. But older galaxies are nearer galaxies, and in fact we observe the opposite effect - we see increased redshifts in the light from more distant/younger galaxies.

You could *maybe* reproduce the redshifts that we observe (which fit [Hubble's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law)) with some fine tuning of parameters - but then you have to explain why and how the parameters in your theory are fine tuned to fit observations which can be explained by the much simpler explanation of an expanding universe.

Comment: Thank you, yours is the sort of response I was looking for! But now I am curious, would you be willing to elaborate, what sort of parameters are you referring to, that would need to be tuned in order for my hypothesis to maybe reproduce the redshifts we observe?

Comment: @roland To make your idea quantitative you need to define how the curvature of spacetime will change and what other attributes it depends on. So you will have to come up with an expression or formula for the curvature value, and this formula will involve some parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that there is no reason why the spacetime curvature in and around galaxies should increase with time. Thus the first step in the hypothesis is to abandon General Relativity - an extremely successful theory that has passed all observational tests and which predicts that the universe should be expanding (or contracting); but then the rest of the hypothesis is couched in terms of a General Relativistic explanation of redshift involving curved spacetime...?

Leaving that aside, the effect described is the opposite way around to explain redshift and the expansion of the universe. When we look to greater distances we see younger galaxies - so these (in your hypothesis) are the ones which have the least curvature around them and should show smaller redshifts in a non-expanding universe.

Comment: To clarify - in my hypothesis, far away young galaxies would look redshifted, because we observers are in a deep gravitational well by now. For completeness, I imagined this well extends hierarchically over / is partially shared by bigger local galaxy clusterings and so on.

Comment: @RolandPihlakas that would produce a blue shift.